# ATU report isn't work with Maven Tool when run as 'mvn test'

Tags: maven, selenium, automation, pom.xml

I have used ATU Reports in my framework(MAVEN build Framework).When i am executing the testng.xml file then everything works fine.

Pre-Requisite:

1. As dependencies are not available for ATU reports so i'm not able to add in pom.xml,i've manually added the JARs in build path of the project.
2. ATU Report is a listener and i defined listeners properly in the testng.xml file.

Issue :

When i try running the project as maven test from eclipse or command prompt, I'm getting compilation error.(All the errors are related to ATU reports)
Reasons may be ...
1. Dependencies not added to the pom.xml
2.defining the listeners in the pom.xml file.(no proper idea )

Please let me know if you have worked with ATU Reports using MAVEN build tool.Thanks !

Comment: Stacktraces, please.

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) on project Hurray: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException:
[ERROR] Listener atu.testng.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListener was not found in project's classpath
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.initializeConfiguration(TestNG.java:907)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)

Comment: Hi Andrew, You have some idea how we can fix this ? you know there is no issue when i run  with testng.xml but while run it as maven test then i am getting this issue.. @AndrewRegan

Comment: Hi All,I've solved the issue for this...                                                                      Reason : External JAR not added to Maven repo                                             Solution : Need to install JAR manually in maven, and the add the dependencies in the pom.xml file                                                                   Please reach me on patroramnarayan1@gmail.com for more info

Answer (score 2):

You can place the external jar in `/project/lib` folder and below dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>atu.testng.reports.ATUReports</groupId>
            <artifactId>atu-reports</artifactId>
            <version>5.5_BETA</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/ATUReporter_Selenium_testNG_5.5_BETA.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

2.defining the listeners in the pom.xml file.(no proper idea )

Ans: In your testng.xml you have to define the listeners for ATU so that it can capture the reports for you. like below.

```
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.ATUReportsListener"/>
    <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.ConfigurationListener"/>
    <listener class-name="atu.testng.reports.listeners.MethodListener"/>
</listeners>
```